# defined name & auto fill cell with pattern based on defined name

Tags: excel, vba, encoding, pattern-matching, user-defined-functions

Please help to create VBA code. I want to defined name based on below picture. i want to make a defined name (Process 1, Process 2, Process 3) with many part number

[image]

Then please help me program a function based on defined name.

[image]

let say if use any part number, so it will declare which process it belong.
So for the function it will automatic fill the cell with pattern. which it means, the part number no need the process and it fill the cell with 75%gray pattern

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

- Achieving this without VBA code can be done through Conditional Formatting. The advantage is that cell fillings will automatically update when users change the part number. In contrast, with VBA code, users need to run the code again to refresh the fillings.

1. Select B1:D9
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F3</kbd>
3. Select `Top row`, click <kbd>OK</kbd> to create three defined names

[image]

Add Conditional Formatting, eg. for PROCESS 1

4. Select `G2:G8`, press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, select `K2:L8`
5. Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula

- Input formula `=COUNTIF(PROCESS_1,$B2)`
- Set format as 75% gray pattern

6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to add it

[image]

7. Follow similar steps to add Conditional Formatting for PROCESS 2 and 3

[image]

The output appears as follows, with the last row lacking filled cells because "57S05050" is not in the PROCESS_1 list.

- Adding `For` loop to iterate each row and apply solver

[image]